# Great difference in Time Execution Groovy vs Beanshell

Tags: java, performance, groovy, performance-testing, beanshell

I'm interpreting a same script in both Groovy and Beanshell.

Groovy takes a very long time(26 mins 25 secs), while Beanshell takes only 20 secs.

I'm very astonished by the difference and I don't understand why, Is Beanshell is better? Am I using Groovy is wrong?

**Groovy code**:

```
public  void calcule_irg(double salaire) throws Throwable{
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.setVariable("MNT_943", 0);
       String script="double formule_irg(Double salaireSoumis) {\n" +
"    int salaire = salaireSoumis.intValue();\n" +
"    salaire = salaire / 10 * 10;\n" +
"                \n" +
"    Double impots = 0.0;\n" +
"                \n" +
"    if (salaire >= 15000 && salaire <= 22500) {\n" +
"        impots = ((salaire - 10000) * 0.2) - 1000.0;\n" +
"    } else if (salaire > 22500 && salaire <= 30000) {\n" +
"        impots = ((salaire - 10000) * 0.2);\n" +
"        impots = impots - (impots * 0.4);\n" +
"    } else if (salaire >= 30001 && salaire <= 120000) {\n" +
"        impots = 2500 + ((salaire - 30000) * 0.3);\n" +
"    } else if (salaire >= 120001) {\n" +
"        impots = 29500 + ((salaire - 120000) * 0.35);\n" +
"    } else {\n" +
"        impots = 0.0;\n" +
"    }\n" +
"                \n" +

"    return impots.intValue();\n" +
"} \n" +
"\n" +
"MNT_943 = formule_irg("+salaire+") ;\n";
        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
        shell.evaluate(script);

        Double   value =(Double) shell.getVariable("MNT_943");

    }
```

**Beanshell code**:

```
public  void calcule_irg(double salaire) throws EvalError {
           Interpreter i = new Interpreter();  // Construct an interpreter

        // Eval a statement and get the result
         String script="double formule_irg(Double salaireSoumis) {\n" +
"    int salaire = salaireSoumis.intValue();\n" +
"    salaire = salaire / 10 * 10;\n" +
"                \n" +
"    Double impots = 0.0;\n" +
"                \n" +
"    if (salaire >= 15000 && salaire <= 22500) {\n" +
"        impots = ((salaire - 10000) * 0.2) - 1000.0;\n" +
"    } else if (salaire > 22500 && salaire <= 30000) {\n" +
"        impots = ((salaire - 10000) * 0.2);\n" +
"        impots = impots - (impots * 0.4);\n" +
"    } else if (salaire >= 30001 && salaire <= 120000) {\n" +
"        impots = 2500 + ((salaire - 30000) * 0.3);\n" +
"    } else if (salaire >= 120001) {\n" +
"        impots = 29500 + ((salaire - 120000) * 0.35);\n" +
"    } else {\n" +
"        impots = 0.0;\n" +
"    }\n" +
"                \n" +

"    return impots.intValue();\n" +
"} \n" +
"\n" +
"MNT_943 = formule_irg("+salaire+") ;\n";
        i.eval(script);

      }
```

**Main**:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable{

            Groovy g=new Groovy();// The function mentioned below is defined in a class named Groovy
            Beanshell s=new Beanshell();// The function mentioned below is defined in a class named Beanshell


            String fileName = "c://salaires100K.txt";

            //read file into stream, try-with-resources
            try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {//This file contains 100'000 Salary, means 100'000 lines

                stream.forEach( n->{
                    try {
                      g.calcule_irg(Double.parseDouble(n));//I use either this 
                      //s.calcule_irg(Double.parseDouble(n));//Or this
                    } catch (Throwable ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: When you say it takes a very long time, are you executing this in a loop?

Comment: Yes, **100'000** iterations @DodgyCodeException

Comment: Are you repeatedly compiling the script in each iteration? It's not the script itself that is taking time to run; it's the compiling of it. I think it's because Groovy compiles it into Java bytecode and then runs it, while Beanshell just rus the actual script as it interprets it.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Updated my question with the **Main** method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better use [Groovy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_(programming_language)) 2 compiled statically feature

> Since version 2, Groovy can also be compiled statically, offering type inference, and performance near that of Java

In your case for each iteration call same script outside of the loop:

```
compiledScript = ((Compilable) scriptEngine).compile(script);
compiledScript.eval(binding);
```

Also script can be marked as [CompileStatic](http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.0.html), for example:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
int squarePlusOne(int num) {
   num * num + 1
}

assert squarePlusOne(3) == 10
```

Comment: Main thing is to call `compiledScript = ((Compilable) scriptEngine).compile(script);` just once, outside of the loop.

Comment: added `outside of the loop` comment

Comment: Not the same script as long as it contains the `salaire` variable, it concatenated to it in every iteration, so it's dynamic script, see this line:  ` +
"MNT_943 = formule_irg("+salaire+") ;\n";`

Comment: Do not concatenate the salaire value into the script itself, but use variable binding for it instead.

Comment: Thanks to all, this works, and the time execution is much better